# Closure Compiler renaming trouble due to name property

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a JS file that has some functions in the form

```
var foo = (function() {
   function ctor(){
          ...
   };
   ctor.prototype.name = "foo"

   return ctor;
})()
var bar = (function() {... the same here... })()
```

I give them names manually because some browsers don't support function.name yet, and I need something to reference the function by because of serialization and deserialization. That's also why I have the following:

Somewhere else in the same file I have an array that references these functions like this:

```
var g_somethingSomething = (function() {
 function ctor(){
      this.foo = foo; //this.foo references the global foo function
      this.bar = bar; //these two this.xxx references are just there so while debugging you can type g_somethingSomething.xxx directly instead of having to type g_somethingSomething.types[figureOutThisIndex].creator

      this.types= [
        {type: foo, creator: this.foo},
        {type: bar, creator: this.bar}
      ];
 };

 return ctor;
```

})();

I'm not an experienced JS developer at all so I wouldn't be surprised if this is pretty ugly to some of you. However, on to the problem:

When I minify this using the closure compiler's simple mode, it renames both functions in this example to "a" and defines them locally inside the g_somethingSomething function so that it can still assign the correct types to the types array. So all entries in the g_somethingSomething.types array will have objects looking like this when checking it in the debug console:

```
{ type: function a(){...},  creator: function a() {...}}
```

The problem is that on browsers that already support the .name property, this will return a string "a" if I check something like g_somethingSomething[i].type.name; Note that g_somethingSomething[i].type.prototype.name will still correctly contain the string "foo" (or "bar", depending on which object it is) that I assigned in the manually, because the closure compiler does not rename it.

This is problematic during deserialization (and serialization), because when I serialize certain objects which contain references to these functions in some way, I store their name into the serialized output and later during deserialization traverse the g_somethingSomething.types array until I find an entry which has type.name === deserializedThing.name . This of course breaks because in serialized data from earlier versions of the same website, deserializedThing.name might be "foo" and type.name will always be "a".

How can I go about fixing this? Is it save (and a standard conform way) to just reference type.prototype.name everywhere I had type.name before? An important constraint is that I have to correctly work with already existing serialized data that has the old (un-minified) names contained within them, because the relevant software is already out in the wilds and users have been using it for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your problem is unrelated to the closure compiler.

```
var foo = (function() {
   function ctor() { };
   ctor.prototype.name = 'foo'
   return ctor;
})()

console.log(foo);
```

prints `ctor` in Chrome, not `foo` as you had hoped.

> when I serialize certain objects which contain references to these functions in some way, I store their name into the serialized output and later during deserialization traverse the g_somethingSomething.types array until I find an entry which has type.name === deserializedThing.name

This sounds like a bad idea.

Use `Function.prototype.name` for debugging, etc., not for important information. Most would serialize your data differently, with -- for example -- an explicit `"type"` JSON property or something like that.